# Why is my Excel Power Pivot not maintaining the order of the manually re-arranged items in my ROW field?

Tags: excel, sorting, powerpivot

I am using Excel 2013 and I have a PowerPivot which refreshes the data from an SQL database.

I have designed a pivot table from the data but I am getting really frustrated at one aspect of the design. I have dragged a field named "Room Category" in the ROW field, dragged a specific field in the VALUE field. I have then added another field as a Slicer, which is basically acting like a filter. I have re-arranged the "Room Category" field on my pivot table manually. However, each time I click on a different item in the Slicer and come back to the original item on the slicer, the order of the "Room Category" is set back to the default alphabetical sorting order!!

I have been looking for a solution all over the web but to no avail!

I am adding below an extract of the data that is being used to create the pivot table:

```
Property    RoomCat    Order
  A2          X          2
  A2          Y          1
  A2          Z          3
  B5          C          1
  B5          D          4
  B5          E          2
  B5          F          3
```

So when I've created my pivot table, I have Property as a Slicer and I have manually re-arranged the RoomCat to show as follows for Property A2: Y,X and Z. I've done the same for Property B5 to show as follows: C,E,F,D
However, when I click on Property B5 on the Slicer and the click back on Property A2 on the slicer, the RoomCat for Property A2 now shows up as: X,Y and Z

Answer (score 1):

The PivotTable will always sort alphabetically unless you give it something else to sort by. If you add a new field to your data which contains the sort order, then you can tell PowerPivot to use that as the sort order.

First Select your Room Category column, click on the *Sort By Column* button, then select the column that contains your sort order:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: It might not be the most practical solution for my data as I have several business names, each having different room categories in the list. The business names are displayed in a Slicer. If I have manually re-arranged the Room Categories for Business A and then Click on Business B on the Slicer, I want the arrangement for Business A to remain in its order when Business A is clicked back on the Slicer.

Comment: If you mean that Room Category XYZ appears before Room Category EFG for Business 1 but the other way round for Business 2, then I think you're asking too much of the Pivot. If those categories, where they co-exist for a particular supplier, always appear in a certain order then my approach will work. If there are some rules that you are applying when you manually rearrange the categories, can you state what they are so that they can be coded?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have edited my question by adding further details on the issue. Hope it will help you to better understand the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why my solution doesn't work for you. The only comment I would make is that you don't need to re-start at 1 for each property - Items C, D, E and F could have 4, 7, 5, 6 in your sort order column.

Comment: I can have Property 1 in my list which may have RoomCat as, say, X,M and N and Property 2 having X,Y and Z. Which Order number do I give X if X is not necessarily Order 1 for both properties? This is why I re-started the numbering for EACH Property.

Comment: If you want X to appear first for Property 1 and last for Property 2, then choose values for all the number so that X < M or N, but greater than Y or Z. If you have two RoomCats that are common to both lists, then they have to stay in the same relative order. If this won't work for your requirements (for example sometimes you want X before N and sometimes after), then its going to end up being a very elaborate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the issue (I've had the same problem with Dates as Text). I think if you create a "Named Set" based on the row Items, it will work.

Comment: Can you add some detail to your answer?